# To convert Set<Long> to List<String> in java?

Tags: java

```
Set<Long> set = new HashSet();
set.add(123455678l);
set.add(124561233l);
```

How to convert the above Set into List of type String ? Without Iteration

Comment: For Java, 8+ use the stream API approach.

Comment: you can't do it without traversing a set